# how to access string indexer on a collection in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Slowly learning Powershell ... I'm working on a script to query a third party AD/AM database (ldap). The specific LDAP property name that I want has a hyphen in the name.

I can do this in c# without thinking about it, but I don't want to fire up Visual Studio just to do some simple scripting stuff that changes frequently.

```
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
.....
$results = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach($result in $results) { 
   $item = $result.Properties
   $item.some-property         # this fails because of '-' 
   $result['some-property']    # 'Unable to index into an object of type System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult.'
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to place curly braces around the hyphenated property name. This should work:

```
$item.{some-property}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the property name via a variable:

```
$prop = 'some-property'
$result.$prop
```